# Managing an iOS app across different platforms

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, ios6

I have an iOS 5.0 app presently and had a few questions regarding deploying the app across multiple platform and multiple OS upgrades. I would like to know if there is a clean and configurable system that allows me to have one project handle deployment to the iPhone iOS5 and iOS6 and the latest iPad iOS without having ugly selection statements everywhere determining the platform the app is being currently run on. So I would like to know if there is a way to manage the code from a dev prespective so i can support all version/platform specific features of my app depending on what platform/version it is being currently run on (for ex. automatically switching to use the longer dimension background images if the app is being run on an iPhone 5 with iOS 6)

Is there any way to have this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am slightly confused with your question, but I'll explain what I know. Xcode already has a way to change your app depending on what Device/iOS Version the user is running. If you use storyboards, then it will automatically resize your app content depending on whether the screen has retina support, and the size of the screen. In addition, you can have a storyboard for iPad, so that when you run the app it will use the iPad version. It also will change the app icons. Just go to the project settings and scroll down until your get to the icons and lunch images.

Now, if you mean you want to change how your app works using the source code directly, then there is no easy to way to manage it. Your best bet is to go with Storyboards, as it makes it very easy to resize content depending on what device your using.

Comment: Currently, the app does not use any xib/storyboard to do the ui layouts and much of it is hardcoded with respect to iPhone 4s screen and ios 5.0 that is why im asking the question on whether there is an easy way to manage the different code changes depending on the platform

Comment: But, do you simply want to know how to detect what version of iOS somebody is running or is there something specific you want to do?